# не могу сделать push в git

Tags: git

не могу сделать push в git, вот что выдает git bash (см. ниже)

```
Counting objects: 20, done.

Delta compression using up to 2 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.

fatal: unable to read f65e27bc5bbfee1f4d7d77f6fb00e0a9952d893f

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git.foxminded.com.ua/Sergey/anagrams_m.git'
```

eclipse выдает вот такое

> Can't connect to any repository: http://git.foxminded.com.ua/Sergey/anagrams_m.git (http://git.foxminded.com.ua/Sergey/anagrams_m.git: Missing unknown f65e27bc5bbfee1f4d7d77f6fb00e0a9952d893f)

Comment: Вы администратор этого Git-сервера?

Comment: не пойму что Вы имеете ввиду, есть глобальный репозиторий где у меня статус master , при чем первый инициализирующий push я сделал , потом сделал коммит , и теперь не могу сделать push , дело в том что только начал изучать могу путаться в терминологии

Comment: eclips выдает вот такое - Can't connect to any repository: http://git.foxminded.com.ua/Sergey/anagrams_m.git (http://git.foxminded.com.ua/Sergey/anagrams_m.git: Missing unknown f65e27bc5bbfee1f4d7d77f6fb00e0a9952d893f)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь получить доступ к некоему Git-серверу по адресу `git.foxminded.com.ua`, вы его администратор?

Comment: 1) [Посмотри здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to). 
2) [Вот учебник на русском](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: 3) [Работа с удалёнными репозиториями](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) Несколько ссылок: https://tproger.ru/translations/10-free-resources-to-learn-git/ https://tproger.ru/translations/git-quick-start/ https://proglib.io/p/git-for-half-an-hour/

Comment: ну как я понимаю да!!!

Comment: "статус master" у вас в репозитории, а администратор сервера — это когда у вас есть доступ по SSH или RDP с учетной записью администратора операционной системы.